# My windows tablet hibernates despite turning hibernation off in advanced power settings

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to stop hibernation and just lets the tablet sleep like android does it? I want to use it as an alarm but I'm pretty sure if it hibernates, the alarm won't ring. I set hibernate to "never".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to completely disable hibernation?

1. Right-click the Start button or press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and select `Command Prompt (Admin)`
2. Within the command prompt enter `powercfg -h off`

Comment: Well, this did fix the hibernation issue so I'll accept the answer. But the alarm doesn't ring when the tablet is in sleep mode... just found out.

Comment: There are ways to potentially mitigate that problem.  You could [check to see](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-can-i-get-instantgo-in-windows-10/9a05636f-f0ed-44e2-8d8e-31a23c4cbdff) if the [InstantGo feature](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2014/06/19/instantgo-a-better-way-to-sleep/) is available on your tablet.  If not, you could utilize the `Task Scheduler` to [wake up the machine](http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/) shortly before the alarm goes off.  Just something to consider.